# ls -lrt showing file which is not present

Tags: linux, file, filesystems, symlink

When I do `ls -lart` in my current working directory it shows

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 10004 36 Dec 16 17:59 index.html ->/home/moviebeam/assets/ui/index.html`

But I cannot see contents of the file.And most important the file `index.html` is not present in the path `/home/moviebeam/assets/ui/`. Then why it is showing up when I run command `ls -lrt` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 10004 36 Dec 16 17:59 index.html ->/home/moviebeam/assets/ui/index.html
```

is a softlink to the original file. It is checked upon creation if this targetfile is present, but once the softlink (or symbolic link) is created, the targetfile can be deleted, and the softlink will still exist.

Should you want to keep the content of the file in your link, while the targetfile can be deleted, then you should create a hardlink (ln instead of ln -s).

Comment: The basically what is the use of keeping symbolic link when original file is deleted?If it's of no use after deleting original,it should also get deleted automatically.

Comment: Well, it was a design decision at that time, and I'm sure there was a good reason for it :-)

Comment: A symbolic link is nothing more than a pointer and can cross filesystem boundaries, beyond the reach of the filesystem hosting the original file.

Comment: @sargant: Ok then how the size of symlink file is determined,if I create symlink to a file which doesn't exist?

Comment: It's the size of the minimum: 1 block, the size of 1 block depends on your disksize.

Comment: @arya - the symlink itself takes up space too. The 36 bytes consumed here are the size of the link, not of the original file.

Comment: @Borniet : Then If I create symlink to anywhere in file-system,do it will always have minimum block size?

Comment: I am asking this because,when I create link to a file which doesn't exist in current directory,It shows `8` bytes.If I create link to a file  which doesn't exist in `/tmp` directory,it takes `13` bytes.

Answer (score 1):

A symbolic link can exist, even if the file or folder at the other end doesn't. If you run `file index.html`, it will probably tell you that it's a broken symbolic link. Removing the original file won't remove any symbolic links pointing to it.